# Cant Login after adding columns to the user table in grails using liquibase

Tags: grails, groovy, liquibase

Am trying to add biodata fields to the user table in grails using Liquibase. When I add the necessary fields in User.groovy and write them as well in tables.xml and run dbm-update, the new columns are created. The challenge comes when I have to log in. I **can't login** but before this operation, I was able to log in with the users who already existed (I created these users from bootstrap.groovy). Below is my code;

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString


@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'username')
@ToString(includes = 'username', includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService

    String id
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String memberType
    String username
    String password
    String email
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

   /* the new field*/
   String dateOfBirth

    static hasMany = [tokens:Token]

    User(String username, String password) {
        this()
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }

    static auditable = true

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        if (id == null) return [] as Set
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    boolean hasRole(String... roles) {
        return authorities.any { authority ->
            roles.any { String roleName -> authority.authority == roleName }
        }
    }

    boolean isAdmin() {
        hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')
    }

    boolean hasRole(Role... roles) {
        return hasRole(roles.collect { it.authority } as String[])
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
        firstName nullable: true
        lastName nullable: true
        memberType nullable: true, inList: ['Group', 'Joint', 'Individual', 'Church', 'Company']
        email email: true, unique: true, nullable: true
        dateOfBirth nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        id(generator: "uuid2")
        password column: 'password'
    }


    @Override
    // Override toString for a nicer / more descriptive UI
    public String toString() {
        return "${username}";
    }
}
```

Below is the code I write in the tables.xml for Liquibase;

```
<changeSet author="okello" id="BiodataFields">
        <addColumn tableName="user" >
            <column name="dateOfBirth"  type="datetime(6)"/>
        </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

My goal is to be able to login and continue with my operations. Without Logging in, i cant proceed to create the fields and design the gsps. Thanks in advance

this I see in terminal;
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
ERROR grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user
.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested
exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'

Comment: I recon there should be some exceptions, sayin WHY you can't login

Comment: ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'
ERROR grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user
.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested
 exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field list'

Comment: Did you have a property in your user class named `cellNumber` that you have since removed?

Comment: Yes. It’s one of the new many columns am adding

Comment: I got the solution to the problem!! The issue was in the changeset! what I wrote as dateOfBirth should be date_of_birth . When the column is added, and I log in its successful.

Comment: Thats why i was getting and error in this format; ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'this_.cell_number' in 'field. Because the system was looking for columns in that format, yet they were saved in this format: cellNumber, hence the error ...